# Can't see the result of a matrix figure using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Would you help me fix this code?
I am using Jupiter and can't see the result. Maybe there are issues with xLim or yLim.

The entire code is below, and I want to see the figure.

```py
points = [[0.3036, 0.1960], [0.6168, 0.2977], [0.7128, 0.4169], [0.7120, 0.1960],[0.9377,0.2620],\
          [0.7120,0.5680],[0.3989,0.6697],[0.3028,0.7889],[0.3036,0.5680],[0.5293,0.5020]]

    theta = np.pi
    a = 0.7120
    b = 0.4320
    shiftrotateMatrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta),-a*np.cos(theta)+b*np.sin(theta)+a],\
                                  [np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta),-a*np.sin(theta)-b*np.cos(theta)+b],\
                                  [0,0,1]])
    points3d = points
    for x in points3d:
        x.append(1)
    pointsab = []
    for x in points3d:
        pointsab.append(np.dot(shiftrotateMatrix,x))
    finalpoints = [np.array([x[0],x[1]]) for x in pointsab]
        fig = plt.figure()
        finalbird = matplotlib.patches.Polygon(finalpoints, facecolor='yellow')
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.set_aspect("auto")
        ax.add_patch(finalbird)

        ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
        ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
        plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If this is the entire code, you should get an error because `points` is not defined anywhere. Please see [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Ideally, we should be able to copy/paste your code and get the same empty figure.

Comment: Points is defined at the first line

Answer (score 0):

Do this at the end of your code.

```
for point in finalpoints:
    print(point[0] - point[1])
```

Every single (x, y) point has the property x - y = 0.56. Your Polygon is being "shown", but it's a straight line.

Comment: That doesn’t make any sense! Still not able to see any figures

Comment: @user11887660 What do you expect to see from a polygon whose points are all on the same line? After `facecolor='yellow'`, also add `edgecolor='black'` as an option and you will see that it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @user11887660 Almost certainly, the operations you apply to `points` do not do as you intend.

Comment: are you able to fix the error, so we can see the polygon ! or would you determine why the polygon its point on the same line